# Adding onclick event after webforms postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a problem. I'm running a postback event onchange in web form control using postback.

```
<asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="UpdateCollection" AutoPostBack="true" ID="BookCategorySelection"/>
```

The asp generates something like

```
<select id="..." onchange="javascript(__DoPostBack(...)); ">
```

and I would like to add something after the postback

```
<select id="..." onchange="javascript(__DoPostBack(...)); MyFunction();">
```

I need to add a call in javascript to refresh some calculations that are done in js after this postback is done. Anyone has any idea? I tried adding it in backend in OnPrerender method of control, but still it's added before the javascript generated callback. I tried also in jQuery but no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution may be to use pageLoad

```
 function pageLoad(){  }
```

it will be called on each postback